# What is the difference between Apache Cordova and IBM MobileFirst Platform

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have to start a project on Apache Cordova for developing mobile applications.

One of the requirements is to use IBM MobileFirst platform. What is the difference between these two frameworks? My understanding is that Apache Cordova is a framework for writing the mobile applications, where as IBM MobileFirst is a platform to integrate and run and test all the mobile components, like an Eclipse IDE. Is that my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is partially correct.

Cordova is essentially a layer between your web code to your native code. It allows you to use native functionality in your web app by using its set of APIs. It also provides a CLI to generate hybrid apps (native apps that use a web view to display the app content) for various environments.

MobileFirst Platform [is a suite of products](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/mobilefirstplatform) offering you a whole lot of different things.
In terms of application development, Cordova is used as an integrated part of the Hybrid application that is also offered by MFP.

In addition to Cordova, though, you get access to other features, not available to Cordova. Such as: Unified push notifications, Java and JavaScript adapters (for backend connectivity, binary data, server-side, etc), Direct Update, OAuth, application authenticity, a very flexible security framework and other varying features. These are things you will not be able to have using pure Cordova applications.

I suggest for you to get familiar with MFP by visiting its official website as well as its [developer center](http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform).